# change html page according to day (mo, tu etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  window.onload=function(){

 var day=new Date().getDay();
switch (day)
{
case 0:
  window.document.location.href = 'su.html';
  break;
case 1:
  window.document.location.href = 'mo.html';
  break;
case 2:
  window.document.location.href = 'tu.html';
  break;
case 3:
  window.document.location.href = 'we.html';
  break;
case 4:
  window.document.location.href = 'th.html';
  break;
case 5:
  window.document.location.href = 'fr.html';
  break;
case 6:
  window.document.location.href = 'sa.html';
  break;
} 
};
```

it does not load the current html page. It loads the index.html file 
can somebody pls tell me how to make this could work ?
thanks!
i've got an array whith week days

Comment: Try [`window.location = 'su.html';`](http://devdocs.io/dom/window.location) and so on

Comment: I have used window.location.assign('su.html') with much success.

Comment: thanks but it still loads the site every second. I just want to load once

Comment: do you have the code on every one of these pages? then it will reload every time you send it to th.html.

Comment: Are you saying that the code does work, but the real problem is that it keeps loading every second?

Comment: it's an external jquery file and it is in every site .

Comment: yes dave. the code works but every second :(

Comment: Like Vero said, if this code is on every page, then even after the new page is loaded, the code will run again and load the page again in an infinite loop. you should check if(day is monday && current page is not mo.html)

Comment: thanks guys. one more question : do i need to check every case ??

Comment: if yes how do i do it ?

Comment: What is your actual desired effect? as even though this code could work, it's not a very nice way of doing things....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the javascript in every page, but only in a "loading" page that execute the code and navigate the user in the correct page.

Loading page (With your script) -> Go in the correct page

Comment: Grazie grazie ha funtionato :D

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your script to something like this if you want to have the same script in every page:

```
window.onload=function(){
var day=new Date().getDay();
var path = window.location.pathname;
var page = path.split("/").pop();

if(day == 0 && page != 'su.html')
    window.document.location.href = 'su.html';
else if(day == 1 && page != 'mo.html')
    window.document.location.href = 'mo.html';
else if(day == 2 && page != 'tu.html')
    window.document.location.href = 'tu.html';
else if(day == 3 && page != 'we.html')
    window.document.location.href = 'we.html';
else if(day == 4 && page != 'th.html')
    window.document.location.href = 'th.html';
else if(day == 5 && page != 'fr.html')
    window.document.location.href = 'fr.html';
else if(day == 6 && page != 'sa.html')
    window.document.location.href = 'sa.html';
};
```